# SQL Injection Questions - Missing Page Numbers

Tags: sql, sql-injection

I was recently trying SQL injection on a public website, with the search field. I first tried this:

> dd blod

But contents are still returned, meaning that it is looking at contents in the web content rather than just the title. Next, I tried to put in a single quote.

And something happened: the results returned are the same, with the same count. But the pages on the bottom is shrunk to 1 instead of multiple pages that I have access to.

Any idea what kind of SQL statement we are looking at?

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: How can you be sure that it uses SQL? It could be using Elasticsearch or any other search engine instead of direct SQL, which when quoted does exact search instead of all/any word search.

Comment: You are right. I don't. I just found this phenomenon (i.e. the number of pages I could have access to shrunk to 1 and but the count of results still remain), and I just want to see if people have any idea how that happened. I don't have a better clue so that's why I put "SQL Injection" in the title. Any idea what are some of the possible causes and what I can do for the next step? Thanks!